# Where can I find a clear explanation of the phase vocoder?

Tags: fourier-analysis

There are many explanations of the [phase vocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_vocoder) online, but they are either a bit light on the details "just unwrap the phase!" or using signal processing terminology and electrical diagrams (this [tutorial](http://www.panix.com/~jens/pvoc-dolson.par) being the most popular link apparently).

I am pretty comfortable with analysis and have a decent understanding of Fourier analysis. For instance I understand what the STFT is, and how to reconstruct a signal from it. I know the proof of the Nyquist-Shannon theorem, etc.

Could someone explain to me (or point me towards an explanation of) the phase vocoder in the language of analysis?

Comment: That Wikipedia article is bad in that it spends half the time talking about the phase coherence problem, never explaining the frequency domain manipulations. I think this site goes into an ok level of detail. Look at the "Processing" section. http://www.guitarpitchshifter.com/algorithm.html

Your best bet is probably to find a good implementation and pick it apart.